# How to change build server's IE settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

Like the user in this post:

[Selenium WebDriver: cannot find element with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701503/selenium-webdriver-cannot-find-element-with-name)

I am getting the "Unable to find element with name == q" error.  I'm able to correct it locally by adding bing.com to the list of Trusted Sites, however when I bush to the build server as part of our automated TFS build process, I get the error again because the build server doesn't have that change made.

How can I change IE's list of trusted sites on the TFS build server?

Comment: You can try to login under build service account and add the site to trusted that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the metod written in comment (just to login and set) there are other methods.

Trusted sites are written in windows registry so it is possible to write program/script to write it there see: [Adding “Trusted Sites” to Internet Explorer, via the registry](http://nefaria.com/2009/10/adding-trusted-sites-for-ie-via-the-registry/).

Internet Explorer settings can be maintained by group policy in domain so you can use e. g.
[Deploy IE "Trusted Sites" through Group Policy 2008](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/325-deploy-ie-trusted-sites-through-group-policy-2008)